# Hadoop map-reduce v/s cascading, which is better when compare on basis processing time?

Tags: hadoop

I have used cascading as well M/R, cascading job looks slow as compare to M/R. It looks me 25% to 50% slow. Is it true or i need to dig more in cascading for optimization.

Answer (score 11):

I can't speak to the overhead of a Cascading job compared to a hand drawn raw MapReduce job as it really depends on the workload complexity, version of Cascading, how you wrote each job, the weather inside Amazon or your network, etc.

That said, Cascading is an abstraction over MapReduce and there will be some overhead. But as an abstraction, it has opportunities to do things more efficiently (1.2 will lazily deserialize data during sorting for example, something a raw MR developer would need to code manually for each intermediate object via a Comparator implementation).

My suspicion is that you are assuming Cascading makes some sort of cluster configuration optimizations over and above the defaults. It does not. So if you run a Cascading Flow without setting any different Hadoop properties, it's likely you will only see one reducer in each job as that's the default in Hadoop (see mapred-default.xml).

Or your job is simple enough it can use 'Combiners', which Cascading does not support directly, but has a more flexible alternative using Map side partial aggregation. This is similar to combiners, but it trades memory for cpu, and they are not limited to commutative-associative operations like Combiners are. Here is a better description of [partial aggregation](http://www.cascading.org/1.2/userguide/html/ch06s09.html).

I should say if your workload is simple enough (and will stay simple) (and [Hadoop is really justified here](http://www.manamplified.org/archives/2011/01/when-is-hadoop-justified.html)) that you can write a couple MR jobs to satisfy it, you should probably stick with that (yet see below).

But the work I do (and I'm the author of Cascading) results in dozens of, if not a hundred in some cases, MR jobs. The fact that I can actually complete my project and get results within days outweighs the minor overhead Cascading may impart in some cases. For example, Cascading has a fail-fast planner, that is, it will not run a Cascading Flow on the cluster if all the data/field dependencies are not satisfied in the Flow.

It is very unlikely you can have that feature if you are chaining raw MR jobs together. it is more likely your workload will fail hours later because of a missing dependency that can only be identified at runtime.

Or, you are passing raw typed 'business objects' around (in order to gain compiler type safety), which means you are either passing data through the cluster unnecessarily, or have dozens of intermediary objects you must manually maintain as you change the business rules of the data processing either upstream or downstream.

Another point on the number of MR jobs. The only way to decrease the cost of a workload in Hadoop is to reduce IO between jobs in the workload. This is typically done by replacing inefficient algorithms with better ones at the cost of adding complexity, adding more jobs to do things more intelligently. So if you think you only need a handful of MR jobs, and you discover a nasty bottleneck in your data when running at scale (which is what always happens to me at least). You may need to take a different approach to the problem that will likely result in a couple more jobs. I know this seems counterintuitive, but it happens a lot. In such cases you will be glad you are working with an abstraction where you can keep your head in the problem domain, not the MapReduce domain.

If you really are concerned about performance, please feel free to email the Cascading mail list with your code, and I or the community would be glad to help identify any issues with it or in Cascading.